# Create custom command to compile LaTeX files

Tags: command-line, pdf, latex

I use `LaTeX` and [rubber](https://launchpad.net/rubber) to compile my `tex` sources via command line. The command I usually use is `rubber --pdf test.tex && rubber --clean test.tex`. How can I create a custom command so that I only have to type `rubber text.tex` or `rubb text.tex` (or something like this) for it to do the same as the long command above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use something simple, like

```
#!/bin/bash
rubber --pdf $1 && rubber --clean $1
```

then you save it in a folder in your `$PATH` and you are done.

I usually suggest to create (if not present) the folder `~/bin` to contain your user's scripts, and then add it to your `$PATH` variable, following [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/60219/29595).

Comment: +1. Notice that in recent Ubuntu, `~/bin` is added by default to the PATH if it exists (in `~/.profile` you should have the needed code).

Comment: @Rmano thanks! I have a very old home directory that I carried along since 8.10, so I missed that change :)